# How can I calculate then display different currencies on a web page?

Tags: currency, shopify, currency-exchange-rates

I'm working on a Shopify site and would like product prices to be viewed in different currencies alongside each other e.g.

£123 | $456 | €789

I've read a few methods on Shopify e.g. ['How to Show Multiple Currencies'](http://wiki.shopify.com/How_to_Show_Multiple_Currencies) but you have to select which currency you want and the all the prices change accordingly. However, **I need all currencies to be in view together** - GBP, USD, EUR.

Is there a way I can set it up so that when I enter the base price in GBP, the USD and EUR prices will be automatically calculated and displayed on the web page? Ideally, the client would like to update the currency exchange rates in the back-end.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you study the way Shopify provides for the currency display, you'll see it is nothing more than a bit of Javascript, connected to a currency exchange mechanism.

To do what you want, just hack the Javascript a little. It is not hard to do that. The entire pattern is already laid out for you in one currency, so adding others is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. Sadly, I don't have much experience with JS - could you please point to the file/code/script I should be looking at and editing?